# SOAP url of arcgis service

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, soap

I basically use REST URL to display feature layer or ArcGISDynamic Service layer and it is commonly promoted by ESRI by their api example. I was wondering since the ArcGIS server also provide SOAP URL along with the REST URL so is it possible to use SOAP URL to configure feature layer or ArcGISDynamic Service  using javascript. So I can put SOAP URL to good use also SOAP protocols obviously has some good advantages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Originally, the ArcGIS service strategy was based largely on SOAP. There were the .net and java ADF frameworks for web development that are now deprecated. I believe some communication in the desktop to server uses SOAP e.g. accessing geoprocessing on server from desktop.

In many ways SOAP is fine for silverlight, visual studio projects or any environment where you have some automated tools to create stubs for communication.

[ArcGIS REST vs. SOAP API](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/9535/arcgis-rest-vs-soap-api)

http://proceedings.esri.com/library/userconf/devsummit09/papers/keynote_chappell.pdf